# NSFetchedResultsController removing and adding the same section results in strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app currently uses a regular `UITableView`, which is populated via a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I also use the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to update the table view. The rows are grouped by sections, which represent dates. This is also handled by the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

It works quite well, except when heavy changes to the sections are done in one step. I give an example here:

My tableview looks like this:

```
[10/10/2016]
ROW 0.0
[10/08/2016]
ROW 1.0
ROW 1.1
```

Now I want to change the item ROW 0.0. I change the date from 10/10/2016 to 10/09/2016.

// EDIT //

To be precise: My `NSManagedObject` subclass has a property `NSDate* startingDate;`, which is stored in the database. And when the user hits a save button I get an `NSDate` object from my `UIDatePicker`, make sure it's not `nil` and set the property to it. Afterwards I save the context.

// EDIT //

What happens is that the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` get's called three times. First with a delete section 0 and then with and insert section 0 (although those two changed order when I executed several times). And then with an update row 0.0.

And what happens is: Nothing. The Tableview is not updated at all (section headers stay the same) and the row which should have been changed is in some strange state where it can be selected (the delegate method for row selection is called) but a different row is highlighted. And when I scroll down no new rows are loaded (I can scroll down, but it only shows empty space).

My NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is implemented as follows:

```
- (void) controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
}

- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self tableView] insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self tableView] deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            break;
    }
}
- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

I have tried another implementation which collects all change requests, optimizes them and executes all of them within `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller`, but it had the same result.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you're doing to the data?  I'm particularly interested in the phrase "I change the date from 10/10...".  Maybe post the code that does the change to the data?

Comment: It's actually quite simple. My objects have a `NSDate* startingDate` property, which is stored in the database. And I do `obj.startingDate = newDate;`, where newDate comes from a `UIDatePicker` and is not `nil`.